# Media Queries in Silverlight

Tags: silverlight, xaml, styles, media-queries, responsive-design

I want to create a responsive layout in Silverlight in the same fashion as CSS media queries but using XAML and C#. Has anyone had any experience doing something similar that could offer advice on the best approach? Examples of responsive design with CSS/HTML: http://mediaqueri.es/

Ideally I think I'd need to have 3-4 seperate XAML styles files. One with a set of base styles and then one for each screen width/threshold we'd need to adjust the styles for (yet to be decided). And then there would need be some code the says, when the browser window is less than 480px wide use 480styles.xaml, when the browser is 481px to 768px wide use 768styles.xaml ... and so on.

I'm a UI designer as opposed to a developer and therefore pretty code-illiterate so I apologize if this is poorly explained or not even remotely possible. Thanks in advance for any help you can offer!

Comment: In win8 xaml you can define styles for different layouts like portrait, landscape etc, and also preview them using expression blend (5). This probably doesn't help you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use VisualState to define visibility and positions of elements. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.visualstate.aspx